# Promiseチェーンの実行される順番が良く分からないのですが

Tags: ecmascript-6

**コード1 ／ 期待通り**

```
"use strict";
var obj = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  reject('テスト')
})
obj.catch(function (e) {
})
console.log(obj);
```

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: "テスト"}

---

**コード2 ／ 期待通りではない**

```
"use strict";
var obj = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  reject('テスト')
}).catch(function (e) {
})
console.log(obj);
```

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}

---

**コード3 ／ 期待通りではない**
・コード2がうまくいかなかったのは実行順番に問題があると思い、全体を()で囲った内容を変数へ格納するよう変更

```
"use strict";
var obj = (
  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reject('テスト')
  }).catch(function (e) {
  })
)
console.log(obj);
```

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}

---

**質問**
・コード3 が コード1 と同じ結果にならないのは何故でしょうか？

Comment: こちらも参考になるかもしれません: [JavaScript Promiseの本 2.3. コラム: Promiseは常に非同期?](http://azu.github.io/promises-book/#promise-is-always-async)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まずは下記の検証用スクリプトとその実行結果を御覧ください。実行結果は nodejs v4.2.1 によるものです。

**検証用スクリプト**

```
"use strict";

var obj = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log("CHECK#1: in promise")
  reject("test");
});
console.log("CHECK#2: promise is created");

var obj2 = obj.catch(function(e) {
  console.log("CHECK#3: in catch");
});
console.log("CHECK#4: after catch");

console.log('obj:', obj);
console.log('obj2:', obj2);
```

**実行結果**

```
CHECK#1: in promise
CHECK#2: promise is created
CHECK#4: after catch
obj: Promise { <rejected> 'test' }
obj2: Promise { <pending> }
CHECK#3: in catch
```

この結果から読み取れるように、`console.log(obj)` した時点では `new Promise()` が返したPromiseは実行済みですが、`obj.catch()` が返したPromise(`obj2`)は未実行です。

質問内のコード2と3は、いずれも `obj2` に相当するPromiseを見ているので、pendingのままになっていると推測されます。対してコード1は `obj` のPromiseを見ているのでrejected になります。

上記検証用スクリプトにおいて、`obj2` が pending ではなくなる = `catch` に渡した関数が実行されるのは、`obj2` まで出力した後になっていますから、おそらくキューに蓄えられて、いわゆる `process.nextTick()` に相当するタイミングで実行されていると考えられます。

#### 参考

- [そうだったのか！ よくわかる process.nextTick() node.jsのイベントループを理解する](http://www.slideshare.net/shigeki_ohtsu/processnext-tick-nodejs)

Comment: 「質問内のコード2と3は、いずれも obj2 に相当するPromiseを見ている」、この説明が分かりやすかったです。質問した時点では混乱していたのですが、obj、obj2、と明示的に分けて考えると、「質問コード1」」と「質問コード2と3」では全く異なる処理をしている、ということにようやく気が付きました…

Comment: 誤ってマイナス投票してしまいました。戻し方が分かり次第戻す予定です…

Answer (score 0):

then/catchの戻り値は新しいPromiseです。

コード１は自分で作成したPromiseを出力しています。
コード２及び３はcatchの戻り値（新しいPromise）を出力しているので、コード１と結果が異なります。

statusがpendingになってる理由はPromiseは非同期実行されるからです。

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(onj);
}, 1000);
```

このようにすればstatusが"resolved"になります。

"rejected"ではなく"resolved"になる理由は、
then/catchで作成されるPromiseは、最初に作成したPromiseのresolve/rejectの状態ではなく、then/catchで指定した関数の実行で例外が発生すればreject、発生しなければresolveされるPromiseだからです。

```
var obj = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  reject('テスト');
});

var newPromise = obj.catch(function (e) {
    console.log('catch');
});

newPromise.then(
   function(){
      console.log('resolve');
   },
   function(){
      console.log('reject');
   }
);
```

例えば、このような場合'catch'、'resolve'と表示されます。
これは、obj.catchで指定した関数が問題なく処理された為、newPromiseは'reject'ではなく'resolve'側が実行されます

```
var obj = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  resolve('テスト');
});

var newPromise = obj.then(
   function(){
      console.log('resolve-1');
      throw 'resolve-error'
   },
   function(){
      console.log('reject-1');
   }
);
newPromise.then(
   function(){
      console.log('resolve-2');
   },
   function(){
      console.log('reject-2');
   }
);
```

では、この場合はどうでしょう？
最初に作成したPromiseはresolveなので、'resolve-1'が表示されます。
しかし、この関数は例外が発生するので、次のPromseはrejectされ'reject-2'が表示されます。

このように、Promiseは次々と新しいPromiseが作成され順番に実行されます。

最後に、rejection関数を指定せず、途中で例外が発生した場合は、rejection関数を指定したPromiseまで飛ばされるので注意してください。

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   resolve('テスト');
}).then(
    function(){
       console.log('resolve-1');
       throw 'resolve-error'; // 例外が発生したけど、次のthenで第2引数を設定していない・・・どうなる？
    }
 ).then(
    function(){
       console.log('resolve-2');
    }
 ).then(
    function(){
       console.log('resolve-3');
    },
     function(){
       console.log('reject-3');
     }
 ).then(
    function(){
       console.log('resolve-4');
    },
    function(){
      console.log('reject-4');
    }
 );
```

Comment: 回答内容を読んで、幾つも勘違いしていた点に気が付きました。then/catchの戻り値は新しいPromiseなんですね。2番目のコードで、catchで作成されたPromiseが、最初に作成したPromiseのreject状態ではなく、catchで指定した関数の実行結果を受けresolveになったことは、結構衝撃的でした(おかげで新しいPromiseという意味が良くわかりました)。また、3番目や4番目についても、具体的にコードを提示していただいたので、大変参考になりました